# How to make panel show up in front of camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have this project where I click on an object and a canvas will show up to the player select an option inside the canvas. I needed the canvas to be world space so the player can move its head and the canvas will stay static in front. The problem is, there is a ton of objects around the scene and I need to update the position of the canvas everytime the player clicks an object.

I've tried to use "transform.position" but it doesn't work the way I wanted.

obs:
painel_escolha = canvas with panel;
transform_tela = camera.

```
  painel_escolha.transform.position = transform_tela.transform.position;
```

Comment: So you want the canvas to be *Headstable* in front of the player? Whic of your transforms refers to the canvas and which to the player? What does `doesn't work the way I wanted` mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to move the canvas/panel in front of the camera and make it face the camera

```
// move the canvas distance meters in front of the camera
painel_escolha.transform.position = transform_tela.position + transform_tela.transform.forward * distance;
// make the canvas point in the same direction as the camera
painel_escolha.transform.rotation = transform_tela.transform.rotation;
```

Doing this in `LateUpdate`(! so after User input and position and rotation changes are processed) makes your panel absolutely *head stable* meaning it always stays in front of the user and he can't look away basically.

Often you rather want to use some kind of smoothed lerping instead e.g. doing

```
[Range(0,1)]
public float interpolationRatePosition = 0.5f;

[Range(0,1)]
public float interpolationRateRotation = 0.5f;

privtae Vector3 lastPosition;
private Quaternion lastRotation;

privtae void LateUpdate()
{
    painel_escolha.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(painel_escolha.transform.position, transform_tela.position, interpolationRatePosition);

    painel_escolha.transform.rotation = Quaterinon.Lerp(painel_escolha.transform.rotation, transform_tela.rotation, interpolationRateRotation);
}
```

this resuts basically in the same end position but makes it looking a bit smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas positions are basically 2D screen positions. You could get the clicked objects world position with transform.position but for a canvas element to point to that (be on top of it) you need to transform that world position to the screen position via https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html